# Event listener on combobox does not fire EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

HI :) I've created a combobox component using Ext.form.ComboBox.
I've added a listner, which a change trigger

```
listeners: {
           change: function() {
               if( this.getValue().length > 1){
                        alert('Val 1')
               }
               else{
                   alert('Val 2');
               }
         }
```

So "Val 1" is fired when i insert a value > 1 caracters.

But when i delete the inserted value, and i have nothing on my combobox, the "val 2" is not fired.

This seems weird to me ! An ideas why this is hapening?

NB : If i insert a value whith only 1 caracter 'Val 2' is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

```
if(this.getValue() == null){
                  alert('Val 2')
               }
               else if( this.getValue().length > 1){
                  alert('Val 1');
               }
```

I think that in the case of a null value the second test this.getValue().length (which was the firt in the code og the question) returns an error, and the program does not continue the execution.

I did not notice it because nothing was displayed in the console !